# Button in google sheets, when clicked, changes the background of a specific cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a button that I created, inserted as an image. I want to attach a script to that image, that when clicked, will change the background of a given cell to green. Any suggestions on what the script attached to the button needs to contain to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, figured it out.

The appscript that works says the following

```
function colorMyCell(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var colors = [
   ["#32ff84"] // These are the hex equivalents
 ];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("B10:B10");
 cell.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```